# Which method is the better to receive socket data in Java?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I try to write the code the receive the socket data by create a thread.But my workmate say that I should use `ScheduledExecutorService` because the thread may be hang or crash.

```
 //this is my code 1
   ExecutorService  executorService= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
   executorService.execute(new receiveThread());
  //this is my code 2
  new receiveThread().run();
 //the thread:
 class receiveThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
               dealWithReceiveData()
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger().error(logMsg() +  ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my workmate's suggestion:

```
   private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
   scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new receiveThread(),0,30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is my workmate's suggestion right?I think the two way is the same effect because I have add `try catch`

Comment: These two pieces of code do different things. Yours runs it once, theirs runs it once every 30 seconds. You cannot compare them.

Comment: @Michael,but I have add while(true), the second times seems never  run

Comment: Rather, the second one starts an infinite loop every 30 seconds, whereas the first one starts one infinite loop. I don't remember the semantics of `scheduleAtFixedRate`, but I'm pretty sure it's not going to be happy about it. It should be a `Runnable` that can be finished, then you *could* use scheduling if you want to.

Comment: @Kayaman,I have test scheduleAtFixedRate,If the first  time not finish, the second time will not start.

Comment: Well, whatever the miscommunication, the premise is basically correct, except you can't have the infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable ... without a clearer explanation of what these are all supposed to do.  (I think you would be better off sorting this out with your workmate!)

Comment: My workmate say the the thread may be hang or crash, but I think I have add try catch, and it should not  happen.@StephenC

Comment: with `new receiveThread().run();` you are screwing the purpose of threads. You should use `start()` method.

Comment: This may help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680259/using-sockets-to-send-and-receive-data

Comment: ExecutorService also uses threads, which can hang or crash.

Comment: My class is implements Runnable,it do not have start() mthod.@Omid.N

Comment: @flower It is `Thread` that has the `start()` method. If you're just going to `run()` your own `Runnable`, OK, but don't think of it as multithreading. It isn't.