# Java: Read socket

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Client

```
public static DataOutputStream toServer = null;
Socket SMTPSocket;
SMTPSocket = new Socket("localhost", 222);

toServer = new DataOutputStream(SMTPSocket.getOutputStream());
inl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("Which file do you want to stream?");
String requested_file= inl.readLine(); //read from keyboard
toServer.writeBytes(requested_file);//send to server the keyword
toServer.flush();
```

Server

```
ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(222);
Socket connsock = null;
connsock = ssock.accept();

fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connsock.getInputStream()));

String requested_file = fromClient.readLine();// read keyword from client
System.out.println(requested_file);
```

It is a simple send-receive programm. As i saw my client sends data, but server cant read them. Please help,
What is wrong?

Comment: can you show the part where you create the socket on each side?

Comment: also, have you tried to `flush()` after `writeBytes(..)` ? (see more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680259/using-sockets-to-send-and-receive-data)

Comment: @MoeNeuron i added the socket part to my code

Comment: i tried to ```flush()``` after ```writeBytes()``` but i dont see any changes.. im so confused

Comment: still can't see how `ssock` is initialized? Please provide more info about the output on both sides.

Comment: @MoeNeuron thank you for your interest, i updated my code. Please check

Comment: In principle this should actually work, assuming you `sudo java x` your java programs. Choose any usable port > 1023  (less than that are system ports - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports)

Comment: Please see also how one can put his questions in a better shape (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is just a code fragment, not runnable (or even compilable) code. Your writing and reading code is incompatible. In general, I/O classes come in pairs, one for reading and one for writing. The methods may also pair up, so that `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` should be paired with `DataInputStream.readUTF`. You can decide which pair you want, but `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` together with `DataInputStream.readUTF` should work for at least the little fragment you provided.